# Looping through Xml data to output result

Tags: c#, linq, xml-parsing, linq-to-xml

```
var runnerElement = xDox.Descendants("User")
      .SingleOrDefault(u => u.Element("Name").Value == "David");

if (runnerElement != null)
{
    var result = runnerElement.Descendants("Runners")
      .Select(a => new
        {

            Date = DateTime.Parse(a.Element("Date").Value),
            MyLength = int.Parse(a.Element("Length").Value)
            City = a.Element("City").Value,
        })
      .Where(a => a.Date >= DateTime.Parse("3/29/2012")
                && a.Date <= DateTime.Parse("8/29/2012"))

      .GroupBy(a => a.City)
      .Select(g => new {City = g.Key, Avg = g.Average(x => x.MyLength)});
}
```

How would you loop through this data so it can give me an output something like this

```
User:David
Date:3/29/2012 to 8/29/2012
Average Distance in Paris : //Data
Average Distance in Madrid: //Data
```

I try to clarified my code a little bit more..

Comment: You haven't selected `User` and `Date` in your query ? how are you going to get that ? Are you going to get them separately, then you can simply use a foreach loop on the result and display it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To correct my previous answer, it should have a method, assume `GetData` with relevant input, so you can use `StringBuilder` to build string:

```
public string GetData(string userName, DateTime fromDate, DateTime toDate)
{
     var userElement = xDox.Descendants("User")
            .SingleOrDefault(u => u.Element("Name").Value == userName);

    var builder = new StringBuilder();

    if (userElement != null)
    {
        var result = userElement.Descendants("Attempts")
            .Select(a => new
                {
                    Place = a.Element("Place").Value,
                    Date = DateTime.Parse(a.Element("Date").Value),
                    Distance = int.Parse(a.Element("Distance").Value)
                })

            .Where(a => a.Date >= fromDate
                        && a.Date <= toDate)

            .GroupBy(a => a.Place)
            .Select(g => new {Place = g.Key, Avg = g.Average(x => x.Distance)});

        builder.AppendFormat("User:{0}", userName);
        builder.AppendLine();

        builder.AppendFormat("Date:{0} to {1}", fromDate, toDate);
        builder.AppendLine();

        foreach (var item in result)
        {
            builder.AppendFormat("Average Distance in {0}: {1}", 
                                               item.Place, item .Avg);
            builder.AppendLine();
        }
    }

    return builder.ToString();
}
```

In order to use:

```
var fromDate = DateTime.Parse("8/30/2012");
var toDate = DateTime.Parse("10/1/2012");

string result = GetData("David", fromDate, toDate);
```

Comment: Im getting this error:The name 'r' does not exist in the current context

Comment: @IsraelRodriguez: I have changed to item, check again

Comment: Sorry for the stupid questions but also what kind of parameters does GetData have, can i do something like this GetData("David","8/30/2012","10/1/2012"

Comment: If i would display it on a listbox, could i do something like mylistbox.Items.add(result)  ?

Comment: @IsraelRodriguez: thank, better if you use TextBox with Multline

Comment: Ok i got it to work, i just need to do a new line for every place

Answer (score 1):

Well you've lost the first two bits of information in the query (but they're hard-coded anyway), but for the "average distance" bit, it's as simple as:

```
foreach (var item in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Average Distance in {0}: {1}", item.Place, item.Avg);
}
```

Is that all you're after? Obviously you need that to be within the `if` block so that `result` is in scope.